# Forcing list box to update in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listbox which contains lines of a script file to be executed. I intend breakpoint lines in the script to show up red, so in the style for the list box container I've got

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsBreakpointLineConverter}">
            <Binding Path="DataContext" ElementName="scriptListBox"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

The converter IsBreakpointLineConverter takes as the first argument my ViewModel, which has a method GetCommandAtLineNumber( int line ), and as a second argument the line number of the script command:

```
public class IsBreakpointLineConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object [] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        ScriptViewModel svm = (ScriptViewModel)values[0];
        int line = (int)values[1];
        ScriptCommand command = svm.GetCommandAtLine( line );
        return command != null && command.IsBreakpoint;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

My ViewModel also implements a command to toggle the breakpoint status of a command

```
    private void toggleBreakpoint( object arg )
    {
        Debug.Assert( _selectedCommand != null );

        SelectedLineIsBreakpoint = !SelectedLineIsBreakpoint;
    }
```

and this works great, but it doesn't update the ListBox. If I select a new script, and then the old one, the breakpoint line shows in red; ergo, I need a way to ensure the list box contents are refreshed when a breakpoint line is toggled. Now stuck!

**EDIT** if I add the following hideous hack to toggleBreakpoint, things work as intended:

```
    private void toggleBreakpoint( object arg )
    {
        Debug.Assert( _selectedCommand != null );

        SelectedLineIsBreakpoint = !SelectedLineIsBreakpoint;
        _scriptLines = new List<string>( _scriptLines );
        OnPropertyChanged( "ScriptLines" );
    }
```

Comment: Are you using NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @wgraham yes: but what property changes when I toggle the breakpoint status? Nothing that seems to affect the listbox content. I tried adding OnPropertyChanged( "DataContext" ) hoping that would flush changes through, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want for the UI to change when the `IsBreakpoint` property of `ScriptCommand` changes, but you don't have anything bound to this property. The `ItemsSource` property of your `ListBox` is presumably bound to a collection of either Model or ViewModel objects. Is it a collection of `ScriptCommand` objects? You could turn the `IsBreakpoint` property into a dependency property and bind directly to that property from the UI with something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBreakpoint}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

If adding dependency properties to `ScriptCommand` breaks your architecture, you should add a new ViewModel class to represent this.

Comment: The ListBox is bound to lines of text - this is because they are decoded from script commands and need to be tabbed and formatted. My ViewModel keeps a mapping from line number to command, hence the converter.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I highly recommend you create a VM class for these items. I see in the comments above that you are trying to force a property update notification on one of the bound properties, but that isn't going to work. The source of the property must send that notification.

Comment: Dumb question for you @Michael Gunter: does this mean I need to create a ScriptLineViewModel **and** a ScriptLineView ? If so, how do I avoid mixing Views and ViewModels (because my ViewModel would need to create the views for each of the lines?)

Comment: Depends on how strict you want to be. You could just expose your `ScriptCommand` objects as a collection available via a property on `ScriptViewModel`. A `ScriptLineViewModel` is a good idea, though. You'll find all sorts of problems that are solved by having one. For example, if you want to enable the user to execute a command when a line is selected, a `ScriptLineViewModel` is a great place to put `ICommand` properties.

Comment: Whether you extend this idea to `ScriptLineView` is up to you. I usually wait until I have a good case before making these kind of decisions.